# Determining K-means cluster numbers in Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, data-mining

I have a trajectory dataset saved in a ***.csv** file and I sorted it according to month. I mean, I splitted it into different files according to month. Number of records in each file is different. For example, in January I have 10 thousands records but in April I have five hundred thousands records.

I am going to perform **k-mean** clustering in python on each file. Could you please let me know how can I find or determine **the best cluster number to initial K**?

Thank you

Comment: How do you define "best"? What was the problem when you tried different numbers?

Comment: @mkrieger1 k-means clustering performance and accuracy is strongly depends on the cluster number. K-mean mostly can be perform according to different k values then it leads to different results!!!. Determining the cluster number is an important challenge. The best is a measure can help me to achieve the best accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [elbow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)) method.

> In cluster analysis, the elbow method is a heuristic used in
> determining the number of clusters in a data set. The method consists
> of plotting the explained variation as a function of the number of
> clusters, and picking the elbow of the curve as the number of clusters
> to use. The same method can be used to choose the number of parameters
> in other data-driven models, such as the number of principal
> components to describe a data set.

Don't let the above description scare you, it's actually quite an easy thing to do. Here's a quick [tutorial](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/elbow-method-for-optimal-value-of-k-in-kmeans/amp/).